# How to read GraphQL query result in Quarkus Application

Tags: java, rest, graphql, quarkus, endpoint

I am very new to GraphQL and Quarkus. I have managed to run a quarkus application with GraphQL
[following this link](https://quarkus.io/guides/smallrye-graphql)

I have the following classes: 
*Hero.java*

```
package org.acme;
import java.util.*;

public class Hero {

    public String name;
    public  String surname;
    public Double height;
    public Integer mass;
    public Boolean darkSide;
    public LightSaber lightSaber;
    public static  List<Integer> episodeIds = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

*Film.java*

```
package org.acme;
import java.time.LocalDate;
public class Film {

    public String title;
    public Integer episodeID;
    public String director;
    public LocalDate releaseDate;

}
```

*Main file where I am defining the query:*

```
package org.acme; 
import java.util.List;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.graphql.*; 
import io.vertx.core.http.impl.ServerWebSocketImpl;

@GraphQLApi
public class FilmResources {
    @Inject
    GalaxyService service;

    @Query("allFilms") 
    @Description("Get all Films from a galaxy far far away") 
    public List<Film> getAllFilms() {
        return service.getAllFilms();
    }

    @Query("allHeroes")
    @Description("Get all heroes name")
    public List<Hero> getAllHeroes()
    {
        return service.getAllHeroes(); 
    }
   
    @Query("getFilm")
    @Description("Get a film by it's id")
    public Film getFilm(@Name("filmId") int id)
    {
        return service.getFilm(id); 
    }

    // @Query("getFilmHeroes")
    // @Description("Get heroes by film specified")
    public List<Hero> heroes(@Source Film film) { 
        return service.getHeroesByFilm(film);
    }
}
```

I run the following query on GraphQL Ui http://localhost:8080/q/graphql-ui:

```
  query getFilmHeroes {
  getFilm(filmId: 1) {
    title
    director
    releaseDate
    episodeID
    heroes {
      name
      height
      mass
      darkSide
      lightSaber
    }
  }
}
```

And I get the following json:

```
{
  "data": {
    "getFilm": {
      "title": "The Empire Strikes Back",
      "director": "George Lucas",
      "releaseDate": "1980-05-21",
      "episodeID": 5,
      "heroes": [
        {
          "name": "Luke",
          "height": 1.7,
          "mass": 73,
          "darkSide": false,
          "lightSaber": "GREEN"
        },
        {
          "name": "Leia",
          "height": 1.5,
          "mass": 51,
          "darkSide": false,
          "lightSaber": null
        },
        {
          "name": "Darth",
          "height": 1.9,
          "mass": 89,
          "darkSide": true,
          "lightSaber": "RED"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My question where does the result of the query (this json file) is located? How can I read it in my program. Please refer me to some reading material or the steps I need to follow to read this query in my program.

[GraphQL Query and result looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P25Ri.png)
[Quarkus Setup looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7Enh.png)

Answer (score 0):

What you've been playing with is the server-side Quarkus extension for GraphQL. But Quarkus also has a client-side extension: `quarkus-smallrye-graphql`. That offers a library that can call remote (or local...) GraphQL servers and lets you work with the results programmatically. The guide for trying it is at https://quarkus.io/guides/smallrye-graphql-client - give it a try!